# python - pandas - dataframe - data padding multidimensional statistics

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, statistics, padding, least-squares

i have a dataframe with columns accounting for different characteristics of stars and rows accounting for measurements of different stars. (something like this)

\property_______A _______A_error_______B_______B_error_______C_______C_error    ...

star1

star2

star3

...

in some measurements the error for a specifc property is -1.00 which means the measurement was faulty.

in such case i want to discard the measurement.

one way to do so is by eliminating the entire row (along with other properties who's error was not -1.00)

i think it's possible to fill in the faulty measurement with a value generated by the distribution based on all the other measurements, meaning - given the other properties which are fine, this property should have this value in order to reduce the error of the entire dataset.

is there a proper name to the idea i'm referring to?
how would you apply such an algorithm?

i'm a student on a solo project so would really appreciate answers that also elaborate on theory (:

***edit***

after further reading, i think what i was referring to is called regression imputation.

so i guess my question is - how can i implement multidimensional linear regression in a dataframe in the most efficient way???

thanks!

Comment: This technique is called Multiple Imputation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)#Multiple_imputation). This question would be better suited to crossvalidated.

Comment: If you're asking this question, you're not in a place to roll your own: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html